# How to bind "on-the-fly" Data into Model in NancyFx?

Tags: data-binding, nancy

How can i add generated, not persistent data into my response?

My response looks like this:

```
Get["/GetUserByID/{id}"] = x => {
//here are some codes ...
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userReadRepository.GetUserByID(id), Formatting.Indented);};
```

Now i want to add a generated value into my response, how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Get["/GetUserByID/{id}"] = x => Response.AsJson(new { user = userReadRepository.GetUserByID(x.id) , foo = "bar" , bar = 124 });
```